# Proof that two vectors can not have the same power spectrum when one is a permutation (excluding rotations) of the other?

Tags: permutations, fourier-transform, signal-analysis

The power spectrum being the absolute value of the DFT of the vector.

Has it been proven that two vectors can not have the same power spectrum if one is a permutation of the other?  Where, in this case, the permutation can not be a rotation (in the case of a rotation they do have the same power spectrum).

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Bullet51 is correct, a counter example is  [1 3 6 2 4 5] and [1 3 5 2 4 6].  I am unsure how/if you can select a comment as an answer

Comment: No. Consider the sequences [1 3 6 2 4 5] and [1 3 5 2 4 6].

Comment: What is "power spectrum" of a vector? Fourier transform?

Comment: Or modulus of the Fourier transform?

Comment: Sorry I was not more clear!  Power spectrum meaning the absolute value of the DFT of the vector.  It is easy to generate examples which do not have the same power spectrum but I am hoping for a proof if it is known?

Comment: I just confirmed the counter-example of @Bullet51

Comment: $∀xφ(x,P)$ implies $P$ preserves distance (let x be a signal with 2 $1$s and $0$ elsewhere), hence $P$ is a rotation or a reflection.

Comment: If the signal $x$ contains two $1$s separated by $n$ $0$s, the two $1$s in $Px$ would be separated by the same number of $0$s (in a cyclic order).